# IENumerator Not Yielding Everytime Called & Random Range Doesn't Reset Each Run

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a meteor shower that chooses a random empty game object from a list of game objects. I want one meteor to be instantiated every 2.33f. Then the program should choose a new random spawn zone from the list and repeat until the smallWaveCounter reaches 0.
This code works but it non-stop instantiates the meteors until the smallWaveCounter reaches 0 and there is no pause between the instantiations.

My question is: Why does it seem the IENumerator only yields on the first run? How do I make it change the random object each time it fires?

```
[SerializeField]
private List<GameObject> meteorSpawnSmall = new List<GameObject>();
 private int smallCounter;

 private void Start()
{
    foreach(GameObject spawn in meteorSpawnSmall)//Counts objects in list
    {
        smallCounter++;
    }
 }

void Update()
{

 if (showerStart == true)
    {            
            StartCoroutine(SmallShower());

        if(smallWaveCount <= 0)
        {
            showerStart = false;
        }
    }
  }

IEnumerator SmallShower()
{
    if (smallWaveCount > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(smallWaveTimer);// smallWaveTimer = 2.33f
        smallPickerNum1 = Random.Range(0, smallCounter - 1); // Needs to randomize each run
        smallPickerNum2 = Random.Range(0, smallCounter - 1);
        while (smallPickerNum2 == smallPickerNum1)
        {
            smallPickerNum2 = Random.Range(0, smallCounter - 1);
        }
        getSpawnZone1 = meteorSpawnSmall[smallPickerNum1];//Grabs the spawnzone from list
        getSpawnZone2 = meteorSpawnSmall[smallPickerNum2];//Grabs the 2nd spawn zone from list
        Instantiate(smallMeteor, getSpawnZone1.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(smallMeteor, getSpawnZone2.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        smallWaveCount--;//smallWaveCount starts at int 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It waits every time indeed but you execute the coroutine each frame so you can't distinguish the difference. Change your code a bit like:

```
void Update()
{

 if (showerStart == true) {            
        showerStart = false; //to ensure that your coroutine called once
        StartCoroutine(SmallShower());
    }
}

IEnumerator SmallShower()
{
    while (smallWaveCount > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(smallWaveTimer);// smallWaveTimer = 2.33f
        smallPickerNum1 = Random.Range(0, smallCounter - 1); // Needs to randomize each run
        smallPickerNum2 = Random.Range(0, smallCounter - 1);
        while (smallPickerNum2 == smallPickerNum1)
        {
            smallPickerNum2 = Random.Range(0, smallCounter - 1);
        }
        getSpawnZone1 = meteorSpawnSmall[smallPickerNum1];//Grabs the spawnzone from list
        getSpawnZone2 = meteorSpawnSmall[smallPickerNum2];//Grabs the 2nd spawn zone from list
        Instantiate(smallMeteor, getSpawnZone1.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(smallMeteor, getSpawnZone2.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        smallWaveCount--;//smallWaveCount starts at int 10
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, I just had to add showerStart = true; at the end of the IENumerator so that it would run again. I also learned that to get the random numbers to change, after the smallWaveCount-- I added another yield statement (Which I didn't know you could have two returns but it works) and then re-initialized the smallPickerNum's. Hey, thanks for the help! I feel as though I have a lot more insight as to how CoRoutines work now!